# Where is there a URDF tutorial?

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The link in the urdf page is broken. Is there a new standard for describing robots and sensors? I've created my urdf file, I can parse it, but how do I access all the info?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56537/where-is-there-a-urdf-tutorial?/) by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 753 on 2013-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello seanarm,

I used the URDF tutorials found [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials). As for accessing the info, what kind of robot are you trying to model? Different programs access the URDF, for example with my manipulator robot (2arms) I used the arm navigation tutorials found [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/tools/Planning%20Description%20Configuration%20Wizard). I've had pretty good success with my robot working in the Warehouse Planner and using real robot data feedback. I've also heard of people using Gazebo as a simulation platform, here are the [tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials) for that.

Best of luck with your research!

Kind Regards,
Martin

---

Originally posted by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) with karma: 464 on 2013-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0